# Mocking pyodbc module calls for django unit tests

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, mocking, pyodbc

I want to make unit tests for some django views which use a custom pyodbc database connection

## views.py

```
from django.http import JsonResponse, HttpResponseNotFound, HttpResponseBadRequest, HttpResponseServerError, HttpResponseForbidden
from django.core.exceptions import SuspiciousOperation
from django.utils.datastructures import MultiValueDictKeyError
import os
import pyodbc

# Create your views here.

db_credentials = os.environ.get('DATABASE_CREDENTIALS')
dbh = pyodbc.connect(db_credentials)

def get_domains(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        args = request.GET
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        args = request.POST

    try:
        cursor = dbh.cursor()
        if 'owner' in args:
            owner = args['owner']
            cursor.execute('{call GET_DOMAINS_FOR_OWNER(?)}', owner)
        else:
            cursor.execute('{call GET_DOMAINS()}')
        result = cursor.fetchall()
        if(result):
            return JsonResponse([row[0] for row in result], safe=False)
        else:
            return JsonResponse([], safe=False)
    except pyodbc.Error as e:
        return HttpResponseServerError(e)
    except SuspiciousOperation as e:
        return HttpResponseForbidden(e)
```

Since I don't want the unit tests to be hitting the database, how can I mock the behaviour given that:

- The mock library won't work since pyodbc is a Python C extension
- Using sys.modules doesn't seem to work, probably because the module is being used in views.py and not on tests.py

Here is my test driver

## tests.py

```
from django.test import SimpleTestCase
from sms_admin import *

# Create your tests here.


HTTP_OK = 200
HTTP_NOTFOUND = 404


class AdminTestCase(SimpleTestCase):
    """docstring for AdminTestCase"""

    def test_get_pool_for_lds(self):
        response = self.client.get('/sms_admin/get_pool_for_lds', {'domain': 'sqlconnect', 'stage': 'dev', 'lds': 'reader'})
        self.assertEqual(response.content, b'pdss_reader')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, HTTP_OK)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can patch `pyodbc.connect` without any limitations as showed in the follow example:

```
import pyodbc
from unittest.mock import patch

with patch("pyodbc.connect") as mock_connect:
    pyodbc.connect("Credentials")
    mock_connect.assert_called_with("Credentials")
```

Now the real issue in `view.py` is the line

```
dbh = pyodbc.connect(db_credentials)
```

That line is executed while **your are importing** `view.py` and you cannot control it without implement some kind of hack in your test code like patching connect **before** importing `view.py` or anything else importing it.

I would like strongly discourage you on write this kind of dirty tricks and change just a little your code to implement a lazy `dbh` property. Another way can write your own db class wrapper (better) and patch it in your tests but that is a strong design change and you can introduce it later by take the power of implemented tests.

In `view.py` use:

```
_dbh = None
def get_db():
    global _dbh
    if _dbh is None:
        _dbh = pyodbc.connect(db_credentials)
    return _dbh
```

where `cusror` become

```
cursor = get_db().cursor()
```

Now you can patch `get_db()` and use `return_value` mock in your test

```
class AdminTestCase(SimpleTestCase):
    """docstring for AdminTestCase"""

    def setUp(self):
        super().setUp()
        p = patch("yourpackage.view.get_db")
        self.addCleanup(p.stop)
        self.get_db_mock = p.start()
        self.db_mock = self.get_db_mock.return_value
        self.cursor_mock = self.db_mock.cursor.return_value

    def test_get_pool_for_lds(self, get_db_mock):
        .... configure self.cursor_mock to behave as you need

        response = self.client.get('/sms_admin/get_pool_for_lds', {'domain': 'sqlconnect', 'stage': 'dev', 'lds': 'reader'})
        self.assertEqual(response.content, b'pdss_reader')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, HTTP_OK)
```

I left out the detail of how `mock_cursor` should behave and cursor calls asserts. You can write it by reading [`mock` framework documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html). I used to patch connection in `setUp()` method because I can guess that you need it in almost all your tests in this class where `cursor_mock`, `db_mock` and `get_db_mock` can be used with different behavior: my experience is that this approach will pay a lot later while you'll add more tests.

Comment: In this case should db_mock be another Mock object?

Comment: db_mock is another mock and it is the same that the patched get_db return in test context